# MySQL subquery required help

Tags: mysql

i am a beginner of MYSQL please help me.

i have a two table images and rate.

i want out put is imgID Rate.

image id as p.k in images table.

image is is foriegn key in rate table.

rate table sample data is

```
ImgID   Rating
1       5
1       7
1       8
2       8
3       2
4       3
1       4
```

image table sample data is

```
ImgID Comment rate
1     good    7
2     bad     8
3     ok      8
4     fine    8
5     bad     7
```

out put i required is

ImgId avg(rate from rate table when compared img id)

for example

```
ImgIf rate
-----------
1       6
2       8
3       2
4       3
```

i required subquery of this output.

thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow Vikram - preformatted text like code or query output should be indented with 4 spaces, or use the code formatting button above the edit box. I have quickly fixed this in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a subquery, you need an aggregation.

```
SELECT  ImgID,
        AVG(Rate) Rate
FROM    RateTable
GROUP BY ImgID
```

If you want to include all images regardless of whether there is a rating:

```
SELECT  i.ImgID,
        AVG(r.Rate) Rate
FROM    ImageTable i
        LEFT JOIN
                RateTable r
                ON i.ImgID = r.ImgID
GROUP BY i.ImgID
```

Comment: but i want ImgId from Image table. because some ImgId are not there in rate table..

thanks for giving reply.